# How to write matrix to multiple ranges in excel spreadsheet?

Tags: matlab

I would like to add multiple matrices to multiple ranges within one spreadsheet. Since there are thousands of matrices I do not want to call writematrix/xlswrite multiple times for reasons of computing time. Is there another possibility out there?

Matlabs Documentation has nothing to offer, I wish I could just do:

```
xlswrite(filename,cell_array_with_matrices,'Sheetname',cell_array_with_ranges);
```

Comment: How are your matrices created? How are your matrices stored? How are you ranges stored? Can you add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Did you actually write a 'slow' version? Did you time it?

Comment: If you are afraid that using writematrix multiple times will slow your code down, you might just want to create a bigger matrix containing all your data first, and then use writematrix only once.

Comment: Consider writing the data to a csv file instead of Excel native file. You can then open the csv file with Excel.